# What is the difference between "utter" and "speak"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, verbs

E.g.

> - speak vehemently
> - utter vehemently

When should one use *speak* and when *utter*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's useful to think of it this way: To *utter* means to make a sound; to *speak* means to make an intelligible sound.

I'm being deliberately simplistic here just to underscore the main difference. The truth is a little more complicated.

NOAD:

> **utter** 2
>   *verb* [ trans. ]
>   1 make (a sound) with one's voice : *he uttered an exasperated snort*.
>   • say (something) aloud : *they are busily scribbling down every word she utters*.

So *utter* also means to "say aloud"; but *speak* has a more precise definition. (And one wonders why "aloud" is needed at all in the above entry.)

> **speak** |spēk|
>   *verb* ( past spoke |spōk|; past part. spoken |ˈspōkən|) [ intrans. ]
>   1 say something in order to convey information, an opinion, or a feeling : *in his agitation he was unable to speak* | *she refused to speak about the incident*.

Not that this is always the case. Every word you speak aloud is an utterance, but not every utterance is of informational value.

Comment: I'd have said every utterance *is* of informational value, but it's not necessarily *language*.

Comment: I've heard "say aloud" justified with "say under one's breath". In other words, "aloud" doesn't mean that it produces some noise, it means other people can hear the noise produced.